# Compile Time Dependency and Run time dependency in Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I am new to Maven and currently trying to understand the dependency management mechanism. Can someone please tell me an instance where a project dependency is required only at runtime and not during compile time?

I am confused because if something is not required at Compile time, how can the runtime dependency be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the use case to understand difference between compile time and run time dependencies is JDBC connection.
In JDBC connection generally we use

```
class.forname( "com.mysql.jdbc.driver")
```

So MySQL  jar is needed during run time, not during the compile time and hence it is a run time dependency and not a compile time dependency

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jason1's answer:

- If you have a container that injects objects (using EJBs, for example), you need only interfaces at compile time, but at runtime, there have to be implementations.
- There are constructions where you compile against "empty method definitions", but use the full methods as part of your runtime environment.